# Display only on first visit > if( ! localStorage.getItem( "runOnce" ) ) { trigger anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript form that makes some calculations, but only want to display this the 1st time a visitor enter to the site.

I tried to add before my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   if( ! localStorage.getItem( "runOnce" ) ) {
```

instead of runOnce, I need to trigger a link. Can you please give advice on how to do this??? Im learning from 0...thanks

Comment: trigger link...what does that mean?

Comment: You could use `window.location = somewhereelse.html;`

Comment: Your question is not clear could you please elaborately explain what should happen the first time the code is run?

Comment: I'm going under the assumption that you have a "calculator" on your page that gets it's values from a form. You don't submit it to the server but simply call a function that pulls values from the form to perform a calculation (e.g. `<form onsubmit="doSomething()" >`). Is that right?

Comment: Works!!!!! i added the target self and its working perfect thanks!! now I learned something new...

Answer (score 3):

The `data-slide` tag is a custom tag for a specific JS script. This is of course the code that does the 'sliding' effect in the website. I've been checking the website. Use the about button

You have the about button that slides to container 834. Add the id `about-btn` to it, like so:

```
<a id="about-btn" href="http://www.inlovewithdeath.com/about-satish-modi-the-author/" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page" data-slide="container-834" data-name="about-satish-modi-the-author">About</a>
```

Now add this somewhere, most likely in an external script and you include it:

```
//  shortcut of $(document).ready().
$(function() {
    //  check if runOnce exists, if not run the block.
    if (! localStorage.getItem('runOnce')) {
        //  we set the runOnce, so this block doesn't run on the second time.
        localStorage.setItem('runOnce', '1');
    }
    else
    {
        // The item exists and set!!
        //  Now we will simulate a click on the about button.
        //  Which should move the user to your spot with your code.
        $('#about-btn').click();
    }
});
```

I recommend to learn pure/vanilla JS first, before using frameworks to get the main idea's how everything works.

Comment: I need to jump to a internal link with the following "aditional information" so it slides target="_self" href="/" data-slide="about-satish-modi-the-author how can I add this information to the location href???

Comment: It is the container with the `id`: `container-834`, so use, location.href+='#container-834'.

Comment: I tried it, it works, but for some reason the theme has a script that slides only when the data-slide information is in the <a> link... if I link to the anchor, it wont work, makes a strange thing , breaks. is any way to include that bit?

Comment: Look my updated answer mate :). Now i wrote it using a hidden a tag. From there, the script will 'activate' the link (with the data-slide included), when the user already has localStorage item 'runOnce' set.

Comment: It doesnt slide :( the idea rocks and gives me more insight of javascript, but doesnt slide :(

Comment: Okey! I have checked out the website again and i saw it contains an `about` button. Carefully look my (new) edited answer. All you have to do is adding an id to the button e.g `id="about-btn"`. Now the new code should simulate a click on the about button `$('#about-btn').click()`;; Haha, i made an oopsy aswell!

Comment: I will start my vanilla JS lessons ASAP

Comment: good to hear! A very good resource: `http://eloquentjavascript.net/` Teaches you about the basics as well.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery supports a "click", "submit" or "trigger" method that can be used to fire an action.  Assuming you can identify the form itself (to fire off the "submit" action) or "click" the submit button in the form it might look something like:

```
// force the form identified as id=myform to submit
$("#myform").submit();

// or click the submit button on the form
$("#mysubmitbutton").click();
```

submit() : http://api.jquery.com/submit/
click() : http://api.jquery.com/click/